# How to allow Cloud SQL connection to instances launched by Managed Instance Groups in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a Managed Instance Group in GCP. It launches instances with random IP addresses. This leads to Cloud SQL connection failure. How do I automatically whitelist their IP addresses when such instances are launched and remove the IP address from the whitelist when the instance is terminated?

Comment: Install and configure the Google Cloud SQL Auth Proxy. No need to whitelist IP addresses. https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy